# Element API using the entries field to display related content from a separate section

Tags: plugin-elementapi, entries-field, json

I've seen similar questions but none seem to help.

I have two sections named jobs and jobDescriptions. I'm using the entries field to pull in a description field from the jobDescriptions section to the jobs entry. I need to output the related description field to the element api but I'm stuck. No idea where to go from here.

The other issue is that I also have a field in the jobs section that is named descriptionOverride. I want to show the descriptionOverride field if it has a value instead of the related field.

EDITED

```
<?php

use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\helpers\UrlHelper;
return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'jobs.json' => function() {
            return array(
                'serializer' => 'jsonFeed',
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'criteria' => array('section' => 'jobs'),
                'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {

// in a section call "jobDescriptions" and called through an entries field type in the "jobs" section entry
                    $jobDescriptionsEntry = $entry->jobDescriptions->one();
                    $relatedJobDescription = $jobDescriptionsEntry ? $jobDescriptionsEntry->jobDescription : '';

// in the section called "jobs" mentioned in the criteria above and used to override the relatedJobDescription if text is added to the field
                    $jobDescriptionOverride = $entry->jobDescription;
                    return array(
                        'title' => $entry->title,
                        'jobDescription' => ((string) $jobDescriptionOverride ?: $relatedJobDescription),
                    );
                },
                'meta' => array(
                    'description' => 'Jobs feed',
                ),
                'pretty' => true,
            );
        },
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `relatedJobDescription` is an Entries field, accessing the field from your `jobs` entry will not return the selected `jobDescriptions` entry directly. Instead, you will get an [EntryQuery](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-db-entryquery.html) which you can use to get the selected `jobDescriptions` from the database. See [Working with Entries Field Data](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries-fields.html#working-with-entries-field-data) and [Querying Entries](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#querying-entries).

To get the `jobDescriptions` entry, you can use [ElementQuery::one()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-db-elementquery.html#method-one) (if your field allowed for multiple related `jobDescriptions` entries, you could use [ElementQuery::all()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-db-elementquery.html#method-all) instead).

Regarding the `descriptionOverride`, that's just a matter of checking if the override field contains some text and if it does, return it instead of the related job description.

Something like this should work:

```php
// get the entry holding the related job description
$relatedJobDescriptionEntry = $entry->relatedJobDescription->one();
// handle an empty relatedJobDescriptions field gracefully
$relatedJobDescription = $relatedJobDescriptionEntry ? $relatedJobDescriptionEntry->description : '';
// get the description override from the current entry
$descriptionOverride = $entry->descriptionOverride;
return array(
    'title' => $entry->title,
    // return either the overridden description or the related job description
    'description' => ((string) $descriptionOverride) ?: $relatedJobDescription,
);
```

You can optimize this further to only retrieve the related job description if the override is not set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help. This got tabled for a couple months and not it priority. That's usually how it goes...

Comment: Well, I'm closer. The related job description is from a different section. Maybe that's the issue. It's returning null but I am getting the override job description if one is entered.

Comment: I got it. Works perfect. Now I have to apply it to several other fields. Fingers crossed.